# What kind of escaping for java applet parameters?

Tags: java, applet

suppose I want to embed arbitrary characters in an applet parameter tag.
It might be chinese.  It might just be a string with embedder single or
double quotes

I've found no statement how this should be done.

```
<param name='foo' value='this is \"a string with quotes\"'>
```

would be my first guess, but it seems not to be good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strings defined in the `param` tag are interpreted by your browser and passed on to the Java runtime. Java itself does not modify them in any way.

So the `param` tag obeys the standard rules for HTML: In its attributes, you can use any character that is valid in HTML attributes; for escaping them, you can use [standard HTML entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html):

```
<param name="foo" value='this is "a string with quotes"'>
<param name="bar" value="this is &quot;another string with quotes&quot;">
<param name="baz" value="using both double quotes: &quot &amp; single quotes &#39;, with some literal 文字 characters">
```